# Meaning of Greenwich (0.0) on GCS_Clarke_1880 WKID: 4034 Authority: EPSG?

Tags: coordinates

This is similar to question topic GCS_Clarke_1880 transformatiom to GCS_WGS_1984 in ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Question : A reply to topic on line above, included:
GCS_Clarke_1880 WKID: 4034 Authority: EPSG

```
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433) Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
```

What is the Meaning of Greenwich (0.0)?
In my albeit but brief time using EPSGs 4012 and 4034, putting the cursor at Greenwich on the Airy Prime meridian, the coordinates provide the west longitude equivalent to the displacement west from the WGS84 Prime Meridian, rather than zero longitude.

Do any EPSGs. (especially relating to the Clarke 1880 Geographic system) provide longitudes which take into account the prime meridian once being on the Airy Transit Circle (or do I need to reduce longitude values) by 0.001435 deg)?

(I am trying to determine the latitude/longitude of sites in NY when using Clarke's 1880 system)

Comment: For the others who may try to give an answer: EPSG:4012 and EPSG:4034 are deprecated. For getting information about deprecated items a user must sign-in to the https://epsg.org site. The Greenwich thing does not come from the EPSG registry, I guess it is something that ESRI is using internally in the transformations.

Comment: `Do any EPSGs` EPSG is not synonymous with CRS.  EPSG is a registry/authority that assigns codes to spatial objects including CRS; other authorities exist